# In Perl, how can I convert multiple decimal numbers in a string to their hexadecimal equivalent?

Tags: perl, printf

In Perl, how do I convert multiple decimal numbers in a line of a file to their hexadecimal equivalents?

I have code which will convert the last number found but leaves the prior numbers unconverted, I want to convert all the numbers not just the last one found:

```
if ($line =~ /[0-9]+/) {
   $loc = index($line,/\s+[0-9]+\s*/);
   $mybyte = substr($line,$loc);
   $newbyte = sprintf("%x\n", $mybyte);
   $newline = substr($line,0,$loc).$newbyte;
   print my_report $newline;
}
```

Comment: Note that perl's `index` is a substring search, not a regular expression match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$line =~ s/([0-9]+)/sprintf "%X", $1/eg;
```